# PowerShell get-mailbox filter on protocolSettings

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server-2010

The protocolSettings attribute of get-mailbox can return multiple values depending upon what is enabled or disabled.  By default, when a new user is created, none of the attributes exist until they are enabled or disabled.

I want to return all the protocolSettings from Get-Mailbox using the -filter to optimize the command by not piping to Where or Select.  This should reduce the amount of records returned before I use a pipe.

Piping Select will give me the output, but again, I want to avoid the pipe and use the -filter:

```
Get-Mailbox  | select ProtocolSettings

{MAPI§1§§§§1§§§, HTTP§0§1§§§§§§, OWA§0, RemotePowerShell§1}
```

Is there a way to use the -filter to return what I am geting in the Select pipe?

I have tried:

```
Get-Mailbox  -Filter {(ProtocolSettings)}
Cannot bind parameter 'Filter' to the target. Exception setting "Filter":
 "Invalid filter syntax
```

Anyone know a way to return all the ProtocolSettings from the -filter parameter?

The full commnad I am using is as follows:

```
get-mailbox -OrganizatinalUnit 'OU=test,DC=Domain,DC=com' `
-filter {(CustomAttribute14 -eq 'Test') -and (ProtocolSettings)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all properties are filterable.

Here's a like to the filterable properties for Exchange 2010:

[Filterable Properties for the -Filter Parameter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738155%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx)

That being said, you can do late filtering on that property from get-mailbox using text comparison (like, match, etc.)  The individual protocols are exposed as individual properties with boolean Enabled settings from Get-CASMailbox.